# Does an infinite number of points in a closed interval imply density?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

It is not very important, but I am asked to prove that the periodic points in the tent map are dense on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Anyway, I can prove that there are an infinite number of periodic points on that interval (and they are unique). Does that directly imply that therefore those points are dense?

I know that all the periodic points are the rationals in this case, and it is enough to say that the rationals are dense, but I was looking at different proofs that all the periodic points of the tent map are rationals, and they seem way beyond this course.

So, regardless, my question about infinitely many unique points implying density (on a closed interval) still stands. Thank you!

Comment: Certainly not (to answer the header question).  The interval $[0,.5]$ has infinitely many points (uncountably many, even) but it isn't dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Not familiar with periodic points, but infinitely many unique points on a closed interval being dense there is not true, just take some strictly increasing Cauchy sequence on that interval, then there is some non-zero open interval between any 2 consecutive points, existence of just 1 such interval is enough to imply non-density.

Comment: You need to show that there is a periodic point in every subinterval.  There being an infinite number contained in the whole interval doesn't help you, because it doesn't rule out the possibility that they all avoid some tiny subinterval, and so aren't dense there.